# pgs4a error identifier expected

Tags: android, python, compilation

I am using pgs4a in order to convert my pygame program into an android application.Things seemed to be going well, but after running the build command I ran into this problem:

```
error: <identifier> expected
```

Which was followed by:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/will/pgs4a-0.9.4/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/will/pgs4a-0.9.4/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the    compiler error output for details.

Total time: 10 seconds
```

The error seems to come from the build.xml file (I think):

```
 [javac] package macwill.maclachlanwill.stairs.;
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac] /home/will/pgs4a-0.9.4/gen/macwill/maclachlanwill/stairs/R.java:
```

How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: I think I have posted the appropriate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have posted, there is an extra `.` at the end of your package. This

```
package macwill.maclachlanwill.stairs.;
```

Should be

```
package macwill.maclachlanwill.stairs;
```